# print to print as comma separated values on the same line

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am unable to print the output on a single line without printing new lines, the following code shows syntax error:

```
print( "tiers found:"+eval("str.lower(tier.attrib['TIER_ID'])"), end=', ')
                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But this works fine:

```
print( "tiers found:"+eval("str.lower(tier.attrib['TIER_ID'])"))
```

the print statement is in a for loop and I require to print the output as comma separated list.
So whats the problem here?

Comment: `print()` is for py3.x; use `from __future__ import print_function` to use `print()` function in py2.x.

Comment: thats an answer do @AshwiniChaudhary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using eval on a completely sane statement?

```
from __future__ import print_function
print('tiers found: {0}'.format(tier.attrib['TIER_ID'].lower()), end=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

One cause could be that the first piece of code is executed with Python 2 and the second one with Python 3.

If that's not it, then try `end=", "`. My guess is that the second single quote isn't actually the quote that you want (i.e. it's backtick instead of single quote or something like that).

Or maybe there is an illegal character in there that you can't see in your editor.